# SQL Server testing for 1 value in multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I am testing a table and would like to find out if 10 columns of that table (integer fields) EQUAL the value 999. can ANY or the IN clause be used for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you know the columns or is this need to be dynamic?  Menaing you dont know the columns?  If you do please provide table structure and we can give more then example

Comment: I believe that you're confusing columns and rows. A result set should always return the same amount of columns.

Comment: @LuisCazares i am not confusing columns and rows...I have ten columns and want to see if all of them contain the value 999

Comment: *"I have a table that has columns"* How many tables do you know that don't have columns? :) To answer your question *"can ANY or the IN clause be used for this?"* probably but that depends on your column(s).

Comment: This makes no sense. Are you asking if you can find rows where the value of every single column is the same? If so I would question your table design since that indicates that you have tables where every column is the same datatype. This question is just not at all clear what you want. Post some sample data and expected output. A vague description of a problem is not going to get you much response.

Comment: Equals or contain ?  Would 3999 pass the test?   You've made several edits to the question with not additional clarity.   Sample data would be worth the effort.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti needs to equal 999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a pure guess, and this is pseudo-SQL, but

```
SELECT {Columns}
FROM {YourTable}
WHERE '999' IN ({First Column},{Second Column},{Third Column},...,{Tenth Column});
```

Comment: So would this return the rows where any of the columns are equal to 999? so for the example where the 1st column would equal 999 but the 2nd column does not..it would be selected right?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you could use something like `WHERE '999' = ALL({First Column},{Second Column},{Third Column},...,{Tenth Column});`

Comment: This works and only returns rows where all the columns have the searched for value.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits it is actually returning rows that if any of the columns in the IN clause equal 999

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits no, it'll return rows where any of them do, not all of them. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8e68fdcc7fc8954a3b74d9d90e2701f8)

Comment: My mistake, ALL only works with subqueries. It should be like `
WHERE '999' = ALL(SELECT Col FROM (VALUES(Col1),(Col2),(Col3),(Col4),(Col5),(Col6),(Col7),(Col8))x(Col))`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to test this is something like this:

```
select * from table1 where i1=999 and i1=i2 and i2=i3 and i3=i4 and i4=i5 and i5=16 and i6=i7 and i7=i8 and i8=i9;
```

where iX are column names. This will return rows which match all the value for all 9 columns.

TSQL is a MS implementation of various SQL standards.